# Function `impl Parser` trait no working with `alt` combinator in nom

Tags: rust, parser-combinators, nom

I use the `alt` function of `nom` to build a parser for bot commands, namely `parse_command` in the example.

```rust
# src/main.rs
use nom::{
  IResult,
  bytes::complete::{tag},
  branch::alt,
  combinator::map,
};

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq)]
pub enum Command {
    Foo(),
    Bar(),
}

pub fn parse_command(input: &str) -> IResult<&str, Command> {
    alt((
        parse_foo,
        parse_bar,
    ))(input)
}

fn parse_foo(input: &str) -> IResult<&str, Command> {
    map(tag("!bar"), |_| Command::Bar())(input)
}

fn parse_bar(input: &str) -> IResult<&str, Command> {
    map(tag("!foo"), |_| Command::Foo())(input)
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn test_parse_bar() {
        let s = "!bar";
        let (_, result) = parse_command(s).unwrap();
        assert_eq!(result, Command::Bar());
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_parse_foo() {
        let s = "!foo";
        let (_, result) = parse_command(s).unwrap();
        assert_eq!(result, Command::Foo());
    }
}
```

This works fine. However, reading [examples](https://github.com/rust-bakery/nom/blob/8c68e22d9f2d0aadaa1770d980d59ea562dfb6a7/benchmarks/benches/http.rs#L79), I was under the impression that I could update the signature of the `parse_bar` and `parse_foo` functions like so:

```rust
use nom::{
    Parser,
    error::Error,
};

fn parse_foo<'a>() -> impl Parser<&'a str, Command, Error<&'a str>> {
    map(tag("!bar"), |_| Command::Bar())
}

fn parse_bar<'a>() -> impl Parser<&'a str, Command, Error<&'a str>> {
    map(tag("!foo"), |_| Command::Foo())
}
```

But then, the compiler screams at me:

```bash
error[E0593]: function is expected to take 1 argument, but it takes 0 arguments
  --> src/main.rs:18:9
   |
17 |     alt((
   |     --- required by a bound introduced by this call
18 |         parse_foo,
   |         ^^^^^^^^^ expected function that takes 1 argument
...
24 | fn parse_foo<'a>() -> impl Parser<&'a str, Command, Error<&'a str>> {
   | ------------------------------------------------------------------- takes 0 arguments
   |
   = note: required for `fn() -> impl Parser<&str, Command, nom::error::Error<&str>> {parse_foo::<'_>}` to implement `Parser<_, _, _>`
   = note: required for `(fn() -> impl Parser<&str, Command, nom::error::Error<&str>> {parse_foo::<'_>}, fn() -> impl Parser<&str, Command, nom::error::Error<&str>> {parse_bar::<'_>})` to implement `nom::branch::Alt<_, _, _>`
note: required by a bound in `alt`
  --> /home/pamplemousse/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/nom-7.1.3/src/branch/mod.rs:47:49
   |
47 | pub fn alt<I: Clone, O, E: ParseError<I>, List: Alt<I, O, E>>(
   |                                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `alt`

[... and same error for `parse_bar`...]
```

Are my expectations about using the `Parser` trait to implement such functions wrong? If not, what am I missing/misunderstanding so that my updated code works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second example, where it fails, doesn't show the call to `parse_command`. If it is exactly the same as the first call which works, then the problem is that you are not calling the functions to return the actual `Parser` implementations, and instead you are passing `fn`'s where it expects `Parser` impls.

So the fix should be:

```rust
pub fn parse_command(input: &str) -> IResult<&str, Command> {
    alt((
        parse_foo(), 
        parse_bar(),
    ))(input)
}
```

To be clear, the difference is `parse_foo()` vs `parse_foo`, similarly for `parse_bar`.